# Unity error immediately after creating a new Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

When creating a new 3D project in Unity (version 2019.3.3f1), I got an error in the Unity console without making any change or doing anything within Unity.

The Error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   VSCodeEditor.ProjectGeneration.b__25_0 (System.String asset) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.vscode@1.1.4/Editor/ProjectGeneration/ProjectGeneration.cs:175)

And the line of code supposedly wrong is from the file created w/ the Project called projectGeneration.cs.

```
var affectedNames = affectedFiles.Select(asset => m_AssemblyNameProvider.GetAssemblyNameFromScriptPath(asset)?.Split(new [] {".dll"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
```

Comment: do you need the vs code package

Comment: @BugFinder or you don't ;)

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Unity Package Manager and find the Visual Studio Code package. Click 'see all versions'. Change the versions and try downgrading/updating (Sadly I don't know which version is compatible). Restart Unity and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The solution for me was to install .NET Framework 4.7.1 Developer pack from:- https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net471

This is quite an old version, however this was the version requested by OmniSharp in the output window of VS Code.

Note: This solution works with even the 1.2.0 version of the Visual Studio Code Editor package.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade visual studio code version to 1.1.3 to fix this error

Open Unity, then go to: `Window->Package Manager->Visual Studio Code 1.1.3`

After that, just restart Unity and it will fix the error.